# query tracks with filter=streamable returning empty list

Tags: http

```
HTTP GET /tracks?client_id=6de7676e249f2b8d4b890b58fb76c1cb&genres=Rock&filter=public,streamable HTTP/1.1
Content-Length: 0
Host: api.soundcloud.com
```

is returning :

```
<tracks type="array"/>
```

If I take out the streamable filter then it works OK, so looks like a bug in the SoundCloud API.

Is this known, and will it be fixed ? I would really like filtering by streamable to work ...

Don't test this using `curl` because it strips out the genres and filters from the URL before sending.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used SoundCloud API, but just from basic testing it appears that your genre argument limits results.

below works

http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?client_id=6de7676e249f2b8d4b890b58fb76c1cb&filter=public,streamable

this does not

http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?client_id=6de7676e249f2b8d4b890b58fb76c1cb&genres=Rock

Update:
Just rechecked after your comment.
This works! Lowercase your genres argument!
http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?client_id=6de7676e249f2b8d4b890b58fb76c1cb&genres=rock&filter=public,streamable

Comment: Indeed the query works when you don't try to filter the genre. Looks like a bug in the API ...